# Windows 7: Safari 5.1.2 PHP cookie issue

Tags: cookies

I am trying to set cookie using PHP on Safari higher version 5.1.2(7534.52.7) with Windows 7 OS but cookie is not getting set in this. This works for Window XP with same Safari version.

My simple code is:

```
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookievalue,time() +3600*24,"/","mydomain.com");
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting all flags for setcookie:

`setcookie($cookie_name, $cookievalue,time() +3600*24,"/","mydomain.com", false, true);`

also be sure that nothing is being sent to the client before the cookie is set. That breaks cookie setting. E. g. some html or headers.